# Run C++ file with input from file in Python (subprocess library)

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a problem with running C++ in my Python programm. I built a Tkinter programm, to get file with c++ code and input file, so that my programm will generate .out file with output.
Using subprocess library I managed to compile C++ using:

```
subprocess.run(['g++', '-o', 'CodeChecker', self.source_code_file_name])*
```

But next I would like to run my exec file with input stored in input_text variable.
Please tell me, why

```
result = subprocess.run(['./CodeChecker', '<', 'test.in'], capture_output=True, text=True)
```

is not working.

I tried different variations, but none of it worked.

EDIT:
I have a button that calls run_code function.

- self.source_code_file_name contains my c++ source code
- self.input_file is .in type and contains input

Code:

```
def run_code(self):
        try:
            os.chdir(self.path) # change working category
            subprocess.run(['g++', '-o', 'CodeChecker', self.source_code_file_name])
            result = subprocess.run('./CodeChecker < test.in', capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
            print(result.stdout)
        except: 
            # error
           print("error")
```

Above code works, but I want to replace test.in with variable self.input_file

Comment: You can't use ```<``` in subprocess.  Redirection like that doesn't work in subprocess.

Answer (score 1):

Redirection is a shell feature. You want

```
result = subprocess.run('./CodeChecker < test.in',
    capture_output=True, text=True,
    shell=True)
```

or, much better, [avoid the need for `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess);

```
with open('test.in', 'r') as inputfile:
    result = subprocess.run(['./CodeChecker'],
        stdin=inputfile,
        capture_output=True, text=True,
        check=True)
```

Notice also the addition of `check=True`; this obviously presupposes that `CodeChecker` returns a correct exit code, and that you want to trap any errors.

If you wanted to receive the input from a Python variable,

```
result = subprocess.run(['./CodeChecker'],
    capture_output=True, text=True,
    input=your_string_of_input_data,
    check=True)
```

Comment: It worked... WOW! Thanks a lot. I spent couple of hours for it...

Comment: One more thing, how should I change your first solution to get input from the variable, not fixed file?
I tried sth like: 
result = subprocess.run('./CodeChecker <', stdin=self.input_file, capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)

Btw second solution gives me strange output...

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the example. Fixed that and added a final example showing how to use the `input=` keyword argument.

Comment: Or do you mean `subprocess.run(..., stdin=self.input_file)` to read the input from an already-open file handle?

Comment: Third example is working exactly how I intented! All good. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying is to use a shell construct, the file redirection, `<`, as an argument to a program. That doesn't work; you're not using a shell, you're just running an executable.

If you want to redirect a file to the input of the program you run, you'll need to set the right parameters of the `Popen` constructor as documented in the python documentation.